# Active record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to insert record from file to database using active record?

Suppose I have a file `test.txt` with the following content:

```
1,20,sonal
3,34,Ram
```

I have a table `students` having fields `roll_nu`, `marks`, and `name`.

I want to store the records of file in table using active record. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It is simple CSV file, so you can:

```
CSV.parse('path/to/your/file.csv') do |row|
  Student.create(roll_nu: row[0], marks: row[1], name: row[2])
end
```